# Matching continous patterns in visual signals

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory

Similar to my question about [auditory signals](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/18340/4397), how do people match visual signals from memory? For example, consider the simplest case where there is a single degree of movement freedom, such as a knob moving up and down in a slider. If the subject was previously presented a set of these visual knob signals and then has to identify if the presented signal was present in the set, what features do humans tend to focus on? Is amplitude, frequency or something else entirely? Alternatively, a reference to what this type of experiment is called would be appreciated.